# Extract specific substring in shell

Tags: shell, awk, sed, cut

I have a file which contains following line:

```
ro fstype=sd timeout=10 console=ttymxc1,115200 show=true
```

I'd like to extract and store fstype attribue "sd" in a variable.

I did the job using bash

```
IFS=" " read -a args <<< file
for arg in ${args[@]}; do
    if [[ "$arg" =~ "fstype" ]];  then
        id=$(cut -d "=" -f2 <<< "$arg")
        echo $id
    fi
done
```

and following awk command in another shell script:

```
awk -F " " '{print $2}' file | cut -d '=' -f2
```

Because 'fstype' argument position and file content can differ, how to do the same things and keep compatibility in shell script ?

Comment: Making a here string out of a `cat` is ..  innovative. Just redirect from the file

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/fstype=[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+7,RLENGTH-7)}' Input_file
```

OR more specifically to handle any string before `=` try following:

```
awk '
match($0,/fstype=[^ ]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*=/,"",val)
  print val
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

With `sed`:

```
sed 's/.*fstype=\([^  ]*\).*/\1/'  Input_file
```

---

---

***`awk` code's explanation:***

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/fstype=[^ ]*/){            ##Using match function to match regex fstype= till first space comes in current line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)      ##Creating variable val which has sub-string of current line from RSTART to till RLENGTH.
  sub(/.*=/,"",val)                  ##Substituting everything till = in value of val here.
  print val                          ##Printing val here.
  val=""                             ##Nullifying val here.
}
'  Input_file                        ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Any time you have tag=value pairs in your data I find it best to start by creating an array (`f[]` below) that maps those tags (names) to their values:

```
$ awk -v tag='fstype' -F'[ =]' '{for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f[tag]}' file
sd

$ awk -v tag='console' -F'[ =]' '{for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); print f[tag]}' file
ttymxc1,115200
```

With the above approach you can do whatever you like with the data just by referencing it by it's name as the index in the array, e.g.:

```
$ awk -F'[ =]' '{
    for (i=2;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1)
    if ( (f["show"] == "true") && (f["timeout"] < 20) ) {
        print f["console"], f["fstype"]
    }
}' file
ttymxc1,115200 sd
```

If your data has more than 1 row and there can be different fields on each row (doesn't appear to be true for your data) then add `delete f` as the first line of the script.

Answer (score 2):

If the key and value can be matched by the regex `fstype=[^ ]*`, `grep` and `-o` option which extracts matched pattern can be used.

```
$ grep -o 'fstype=[^ ]*' file
fstype=sd
```

In addition, regex `\K` can be used with `-P` option (please make sure this option is only valid in GNU `grep`).
Patterns that are to the left of `\K` are not shown with `-o`.
Therefore, below expression can extract the value only.

```
$ grep -oP 'fstype=\K[^ ]*' file
sd
```